How to achieve depth effect (pseudo-3D) for text in KonvaJs
The expected 3D effect:

Code:
<Group
                ref={mainRef}
                x={x}
                y={y}
                scaleX={scaleX}
                scaleY={scaleY}
                onTap={onTap}
                rotation={rotation}
                onClick={onTap}
                draggable
                onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
                onDragMove={onDragMove}
                onTransformEnd={onTransformEnd}

            >
                {[...Array(6)].map((_, i) => <Text
                    text={letter}
                    x={i}
                    y={i}
                    fontFamily="Bangers-Regular"
                    fontSize={fontSize}

                    stroke="red"
                    strokeWidth={3}
                    fill="red"
                    fillPriority="color"

                />)}
                < Text
                    ref={(ref) => onRender(ref)}
                    text={letter}
                    fontFamily="Bangers-Regular"
                    fontSize={fontSize}

                    stroke="blue"
                    strokeWidth={3}
                    fill="blue"
                    fillPriority="color"

                />
</Group>

Result from code above:

vs

As you can see in the comparison the quality of the reference 3D effect is much higher and there is no aliasing, in theory I could get a better effect by increasing the number of copies, but it still looks worse at zoom-in.
Reference from: https://www.graffiti-empire.com/graffiti-generator/

A possible solution is to increase number of steps when your scale is increased:
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Text, Circle, Line, Group } from "react-konva";

const App = () => {
  const [scale, setScale] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0.5"
        max="5"
        step="0.1"
        value={scale}
        onChange={() => {
          setScale(Number(event.target.value));
        }}
      />
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Group draggable scaleX={scale} scaleY={scale}>
            {[...Array(Math.round(6 * scale))].map((_, i) => (
              <Text
                text={"Hello"}
                x={i / scale}
                y={i / scale}
                stroke="red"
                strokeWidth={3}
                fill="red"
                fillPriority="color"
                fontSize={50}
              />
            ))}
            <Text
              text={"Hello"}
              stroke="blue"
              strokeWidth={3}
              fill="blue"
              fillPriority="color"
              fontSize={50}
            />
          </Group>
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-konva-3d-text-fj5gg4
Note: creating many layers may harm performance a lot. I suggest to cache the group if possible.

Thank you @lavtron, do you know if it is more profitable to use Shape and paint this effect on sceneFunc as a single Shape or as separate objects (as in your example)?

Custom shape should be faster.
